# Selecting across axis

Tags: selection-tools, axis

Right now when I'm using the *Select Tool*, from let's say the side of my object.

Its only selecting points from that particular side.

How can I make so that it selects **through** my object so that it selects all sides within my *Selection Box*?

[image: Example]

Comment: The easiest way might be entering x-ray mode and select, but you can also check the option for selecting covered vertices

Comment: The general rule being: if you can see it, you can select it. So any mode which makes a vertex visible will do. Sometimes it's more convenient to H hide a selection to get at the stuff behind it.

Answer (score 3):

Click this icon (see image) or shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>

[image]